# Extracting data from complex JSON structure

Tags: json, perl

I am trying to extract some data from the following is the json structure:

```
{
    "numFailedTestSuites": 0,
    "numFailedTests": 0,
    "numPassedTestSuites": 7,
    "numPassedTests": 29,
    "numPendingTestSuites": 0,
    "numPendingTests": 0,
    "testResults": [
        {
            "assertionResults": [
                {
                    "ancestorTitles": [
                        "propertyReader"
                    ],
                    "failureMessages": [],
                    "fullName": "propertyReader Test method: readPropertyFile",
                    "location": null,
                    "status": "passed",
                    "title": "Test method: readPropertyFile"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "assertionResults": [
                {
                    "ancestorTitles": [
                        "Transform Angle"
                    ],
                    "failureMessages": [],
                    "fullName": "Transform Angle Test Method: rotationMatrix",
                    "location": null,
                    "status": "passed",
                    "title": "Test Method: rotationMatrix"
              }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In particular, I need to access the status and title. This is what I wrote:

```
my $dir = getcwd();
my $jsonFilePath="testResult.json";
my $finalPath=$dir."/".$jsonFilePath;

print "json file path is ",$finalPath;
my $json = $finalPath;

my $data = do {
    open my $fh, '<', $json;
    local $/;
    decode_json(<$fh>);
};

my $results = $data->{testResults};
for my $result ( @$results ) {

    my $readings   = $result->{assertionResults};
    printf "status: %s\n", $readings->{status};
    printf "title:    %s\n", $readings->{title};
    print "\n";
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

> Pseudo-hashes are deprecated
> Argument "passed" isn't numeric in hash element at line 27(printf "status: %s\n", $readings->{status};)
> Bad index while coercing array into hash at  line 27.

How to fix these errors and extract the status and title from the JSON above?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I don't get the same error messages as you do. It might be because we are using different Perl versions. Or it might be because you didn't post the actual code or data you are using. If my answer does not fix your problem, please make sure that when you run the _exact_ code/data in your question, you get the error messages showed in the question.

Comment: The json is generated after executing jest test. The original json has over 24000 lines of code. This is the snap of actual data. Your solution worked for me, by changing to
for my $readings (@{$result->{assertionResults}})
Thank you for the help!

Comment: This changing names on variables is a bit excessive, and it makes your code harder to read. Your code would work with just `my $json = "testResult.json"`. Also, getcwd is quite unnecessary, since Perl will assume all file paths are relative to the location of the program file.

Comment: Note that Perl expands variables in double-quoted strings. That means you can write things like `my $finalPath="$dir/$jsonFilePath";` and `print "json file path is $finalPath";`. You may also find the [`say()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say) function more userful than `print()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your JSON isn't valid: you are missing a closing `]` before the last `}` (which will close the array associated to the key `testResults`). Fixing the syntax of your JSON by adding the missing `]` will fix the following error message:

> , or ] expected while parsing array, at character offset 1128 (before "}\n") at ...

Second, `assertionResults` contains a JSON array (then converted to an arrayref in Perl) rather than an object (which would have been converted to a hashref). Thus, you should be getting this error when doing `$readings->{status}`:

> Not a HASH reference at json.pl line ...

To fix it, treat `$result->{assertionResults}` as an arrayref rather than a hashref. It seems that what you want to do is:

```
my $readings = $result->{assertionResults}[0];
```

That being said, depending on what your JSON can actually contain, you may instead want to do:

```
for my $readings (@{$result->{assertionResults}}) {
    printf "status: %s\n", $readings->{status};
    printf "title:  %s\n", $readings->{title};
    print "\n";
}
```

Or, maybe, you are not building the JSON as you would like, and instead of

```
    "assertionResults": [
        {
            "ancestorTitles": [
                "propertyReader"
            ],
            "failureMessages": [],
            "fullName": "propertyReader Test method: readPropertyFile",
            "location": null,
            "status": "passed",
            "title": "Test method: readPropertyFile"
        }
    ]
```

You might want to remove the brackets `[]` and have

```
    "assertionResults":
        {
            "ancestorTitles": [
                "propertyReader"
            ],
            "failureMessages": [],
            "fullName": "propertyReader Test method: readPropertyFile",
            "location": null,
            "status": "passed",
            "title": "Test method: readPropertyFile"
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please investigate the following code snippet for compliance with your problem.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use JSON;

my $json = do { local $/; <DATA> };
my $data = from_json($json);

say "$_->{assertionResults}[0]{title}   $_->{assertionResults}[0]{status}"
    for  @{$data->{testResults}};


__DATA__
{
    "numFailedTestSuites": 0,
    "numFailedTests": 0,
    "numPassedTestSuites": 7,
    "numPassedTests": 29,
    "numPendingTestSuites": 0,
    "numPendingTests": 0,
    "testResults": [
        {
            "assertionResults": [
                {
                    "ancestorTitles": [
                        "propertyReader"
                    ],
                    "failureMessages": [],
                    "fullName": "propertyReader Test method: readPropertyFile",
                    "location": null,
                    "status": "passed",
                    "title": "Test method: readPropertyFile"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "assertionResults": [
                {
                    "ancestorTitles": [
                        "Transform Angle"
                    ],
                    "failureMessages": [],
                    "fullName": "Transform Angle Test Method: rotationMatrix",
                    "location": null,
                    "status": "passed",
                    "title": "Test Method: rotationMatrix"
              }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Output

```
Test method: readPropertyFile   passed
Test Method: rotationMatrix     passed
```

NOTE:

replace `my $json = do { local $/; <DATA> };` with `my $json = do { local $/; <> };` to read from a file provided as an argument to the script. For example `./script.pl datafile.json`.

This approach allows to utilize a pipe to pump input data to the script. For example `cut datafile.json | ./script.pl`.